# Inequality related to the forward difference operator

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $g$ be any non-negative and non-decreasing function. How can we show that 
$$|g(x)-g(y)|\le||\Delta g||_{\infty}|x-y|,$$
where $\Delta f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$ is the forward difference operator and $||f||_{\infty}$ is the sup norm?

Comment: The inequality stated is not generally true, unless $x$ and $y$ differ by an integer: Take $g$ to be the Heaviside function ($g(x)=1$ for $x>0$, $0$ for $x\le0$) and suppose $y=-x$ with $x>0$ small.  What you can prove instead is $$|g(x)-g(y)|\le\|\Delta g\|_\infty(|x-y|+1).$$ Supposing $y<x$, there is a natural number $k$ such that $y+k-1<x\le y+k$. Then $g(x)-g(y)\le g(y+k)-g(y)$ and write this as a telescoping sum...

Comment: @BobPego do u think one can find sharper bounds by using higher order forward difference operators asssuming $g$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$?

Comment: I don't quite see what you have in mind - For $g:{\mathbb Z}_+\to {\mathbb R}$ the inequality you started with is true, and seems perfectly sharp, providing bounds on all chord slopes in terms of single-step slopes. Probably there is a discrete analog of Taylor's theorem, though, where higher-order difference operators would appear. I can't point to a reference at the moment, however.

Comment: @BobPego thanks for your answer! I am just curious if the bound is sharp or becomes sharper if one uses higher-order differences, say for functions that solves certain difference equations. Maybe I should first look at the discrete Taylor's theorem as you mentioned.